# How to handle multiple clients using django channels?

Tags: django, multithreading, django-channels

I'm building a real time iot Django server. My server should connect with multiple iot devices at the same time. I know that through a django channel I can serve a client. 
Is it possible for a django channel to handle multiple clients at once?If not do I need to create multiple websockets in order to handle multiple clients at the same time?

Comment: Yes it can handle multiple clients just like normal HTTP servers can handle connections from different client browsers and mobile devices. Of course, it creates a websocket connection with each client

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use iot, then I will suggest to go for 3 party solution like PubNub and JavaScript. PubNub has good documentation and will handle most of the heavyweights out of the box.